# Как вернуть вкладку консоли в IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Оказалась отключенной вкладка консоли, остались только TODO, Java Enterprise и Version Control. Как включить обратно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в меню window ищи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы имеете ввиду терминал:

> View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal

или

> Alt+F12

Если вы имеете ввиду Run:

> View -> Tool Windows -> Run

или

> Alt+4